# WPF: Button Click on one ViewModel should exxecute a command on another viewmodel

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, parameters

i am kind of new to mvvm and i understand the basic concpects.
now i have a question:
i have two different viewmodels, which will be attached together on another wpf gui.

in one viewmodel, there is a button and a checkbox; ("left sided control")
now the "trick":
on the other viewmodel there is a checkbox, too. ("right sided control")

now: if the button was hit, then on the other viewmodel should be checked if the checkbox is set, too.

basicly i would do it with an event or a "signal", but the thing is, if the checkbox on the "right sided control" is checked, it needs a value from the "left sided".

the implemenation would be done by an event, and if so: how can i pass parameters??

as i am new to that mvvm i don't know exactly what i am really looking for and which solution would be "state of the art" and "mvvm"-style.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/, it has a Messenger class that i think it's exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the UI interaction sounds a little complicated - it might be worth reviewing your UI interaction - could that be simplifed?  Assuming not (i.e complexe UI need is real):
It sounds like left side view model (LVM) depends on a property of right side view model (RVM).  So is it possible to setup that relationship in your view model properties i.e. Can LVM be setup to hold a ref to RVM and that the property that is bound to the check box itselft checks the dependant property on RVM?  Then your command (bound on LVM) just has to check a proerty of LVM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some Event Aggregator (for example [from Prism library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)) for such stuff. Here is an c# pseudocode example of how to do it using Prism's Event Aggregator:

In your RVM:

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<LeftCBCheckedEvent>()
    .Subscribe(SaveStateOfLeftCBLocally);

...

private void SaveStateOfLeftCBLocally(bool isLeftCBChecked)
{
    _isLeftCBChecked = isLeftCBChecked;
}
```

In your LVM:

```
public bool IsLeftCBChecked {get; set;}
...
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<LeftCBCheckedEvent>().Publish(IsLeftCBChecked);
```

Event definition:

```
public class LeftCBCheckedEvent : CompositePresentationEvent<bool>{}
```

So when that button is pressed you'll already know the state of your left check box. And I strongly recommend to check Prism, it's a great library for composite applications, I think it can add a big value to your project.